# Re-evaluating the notebook takes long time after doing `Quit`

Tags: kernel, kernel-startup

I have a code. After `Quit`, I want to re-evaluate the notebook. It takes about 10 seconds to start the re-evaluation in Windows 10.

But my friend uses Macbook. It takes about 1 second in MacOS.

How to decrease the time on my PC?
What are your suggestions?  (any suggestion, such as alternatives of `Quit` )

**P.S.** Although I use `` ClearAll["Global`*"] `` at the beginning, I don't sometimes get the correct results while re-evaluating. So, I need to `Quit` command to get the correct results.

Comment: I am seeing similar times on my machines. Unfortunately, I don't think there is too much you can do here. That being said, quitting the kernel is rarely required. Usually, you can just reevaluate the notebook, optionally with some `Clear` commands at the beginning. With this in mind, is there a particular reason why you are restarting the kernel so frequently that you are bothered by this time delay?

Comment: Although I use ```ClearAll["Global`*"]``` at the beginning, I don't sometimes get the correct results while re-evaluating. So, I need to `Quit` command to get the correct results.

Comment: Are you using any other contexts apart from `Global`?

Comment: It might be a good idea to determine why you don't get the same result upon the second evaluation. It may expose a problem in your code. Doing this is usually not difficult: you simply need to evaluate inputs one-by-one (instead of en-masse), and find where the difference first appears. Then break down the offending input into smaller and smaller parts until you find the culprit.

Comment: Dear @RohitNamjoshi, how can I find the context apart from `Global`. Is there any code such as ```?Global`*```

Comment: Dear @Szabolcs, thanks for your good idea. Is there anything you can suggest?

Comment: @1_student `Contexts[] // Map[StringSplit[#, "\`"] & /* First] // DeleteDuplicates`. Seems unlikely that your code is using `Begin` or `BeginPackage`.

Comment: What's in your `init.m` file (`FindFile["init.m"]`)? You did say it takes 10 seconds *before* the notebook evaluation *starts*, right?

Comment: Dear @MichaelE2, there is just (** User Mathematica initialization file **) in `init.m` Yes, you are right. I said it.

Answer (score 1):

Possible causes of slow kernel initiation that I have heard of are reading paclet info and slow FlexLM server/licencing.

You could try resetting Mathematica to see if that speeds up kernel initiation.

[Resetting Mathematica’s preferences, caches and history](https://support.wolfram.com/12464)

Are you using a network licence (FlexLM)?